# Android Room: Views via @DatabaseView tag not generated

Tags: android, android-room, androidx

Here is my code. I've done all as explained. Created views tagging via @DATABASEVIEW(value=?, viewName=?)
Tagged the views in Room database class 
But when I query select against VIEWS throwing exception on build process:
**There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: USER_RATE_INFO_VIEW**
I explored the auto generated database implementation classes and didn't find view creating scripts.
[image]

```
@Database(entities = {BankEntity.class, BankRateEntity.class, CommentEntity.class, ExchangeOfficeEntity.class,
        FBankEntity.class, FBankRateEntity.class, FRateEntity.class, RateByUserEntity.class,
        RateInfoEntity.class, UserEntity.class, UserMessageEntity.class, UserRateEntity.class},
        views = {BankRateView.class, ChatView.class, FBankRateView.class, RateInfoView.class, UserRateVew.class},
        version = 9)
public abstract class RoomDB extends RoomDatabase {
    private static RoomDB INSTANCE;

    public abstract RoomDao roomDao();

    public static RoomDB getDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RoomDB.class, "database.db")
                            // allow queries on the main thread.
                            // Don't do this on a real app! See PersistenceBasicSample for an example.
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3, MIGRATION_3_4, MIGRATION_4_5, MIGRATION_5_6, MIGRATION_6_7, MIGRATION_7_8, MIGRATION_8_9)
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@DatabaseView(value = TUserRate.VIEW_SQL_CMD, viewName = TUserRate.VIEW_NAME)
public class UserRateVew extends UserRateEntity{

    @ColumnInfo(name = TUserRate.COLUMN_USER_RATING)
    private float userRating;

}
```

Comment: Is anybody using room component?

Comment: Same problem here, did you find anything working on that matter?

Comment: @StéphanePéchard I tried renaming classes and clean build. After that I didn't see this kind of error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and just solve it. (I use kotlin, so you need to change something correspondly in java)

**1.check your build.gradle dependency (There is two of it, one show in "Android" which is in app folder, other one in "Project" which is project root folder)**

> project root / build.gradle I add as folllow

```
ext.ktlintVersion = '0.30.0' in buildscript{}
plugins {
    id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "3.13.0"
}
spotless {
kotlin {
    target "**/*.kt"
    ktlint(ktlintVersion)
    }
}
```

> app / build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
} in android{}

following dependency seems must at top
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-beta01"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'

this one just below previous mention denpendency
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-beta01'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0-alpha01"

following at bottom but before androidTestImplementation; kotlin_version should be 1.3.31
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1"
```

**2. check DAO implementation that use @databaseview, especially the return type
which must match the query view result Column**

When I change my build.gradle, the error becomes the actual error that makes the databaseview not generate.

**3. invalidate Caches / Restart android studio**

It spend me couple hours to debug and solve this error, wish it can help you.

***(I am not from English speaking country, so enjoy my English grammar mistake. hahaha)***